# Refactoring Database with EntityFramework from code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm in the process of adapting the MVCMusicStore shopping cart. I wish to refactor the database using EntityFramework - not via the Server Explorer.

In my models folder I created a new `FooEntities` model.

```
public class FooStoreEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FooMaker> FooMakers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

I've also created the extra models `Foo`, `FooMaker` and `Category`. The other models already existed in the MVCMusicStore example.

I created a `SampleFooData` class which inherits from `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<FooStoreEntities>` and overrides the `seed` method to seed the new tables.

I changed the `Application_Start` method in the `Global.asax.cs` to contain `System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new FooStore.Models.SampleFooData());`

In the `web.config` file I have:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="FooStoreEntities"
    connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|FooStore.sdf"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Where `FooStore.sdf` still contains all the old tables from the MVCMusicStore application.

When I execute the web app it hits the `SetInitializer` breakpoint however it does not seem to create the `SampleFooData` object and create the new tables in the database. What am I missing? Or is there something fundamental I don't understand?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Database.SetInitializer simply not working...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368553/entity-framework-database-setinitializer-simply-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will only be created when you use your DB context: see [Entity Framework Database.SetInitializer simply not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368553/entity-framework-database-setinitializer-simply-not-working/6368696#6368696)

You could put

```
var ctx = new FooStoreEntities();
ctx.Database.Initialize(true);
```

after where you set the initializer in Application_Start.