# Migrations Seed Method Ignores Seed Method of Database Initializer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, seeding

I'm working on an Asp.Net Mvc application then i want to seed my database using custom Database initializer class that I created.

so here is my `DbContext` :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> {
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("defaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) {
    }

    static ApplicationDbContext() {
        Database.SetInitializer(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
    }
```

and here is my `ApplicationDbInitializer` class :

```
public class ApplicationDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext> {

    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context) {
        InitializeIdentityForEF(context);
        base.Seed(context);
    }

    public static void InitializeIdentityForEF(ApplicationDbContext db) {

        // Create Role Admin if it does not exist
        // Add user admin to Role Admin if not already added
        // And some more initializing stuff

    }
}
```

**Note:** I'm using `Migrations` too.

so when i try to update and seed my database using command `Update-Database` (even if I delete database manually) , the database is being created but it does not seed it.

if I am doing anything wrong or it has other ways I'll be thankful to get your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the same issue as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368553/entity-framework-database-setinitializer-simply-not-working).

So, the seed code will only run when you create an instance of your `ApplicationDbContext`.

Add some code like this to your application startup:

```
var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext();
ctx.Database.Initialize(true);
```

Then your database will be seeded the next time your app starts.

Alternatively, if you wanted to use the `Update-Database` command to seed your database, that uses a *different* `Seed` method. You can see an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3).